# Implementing Google Maps in QlikView 11

Tags: qlikview

I am trying to implement google map in Qlikview.

I have Newjersey county information with latitude and  longitude. I am trying to get static google API key but getting the following error.
Please let me know how to get new version of API key.

Error:

The Static API v1 has been deprecated as of 2009, and truned down in January 2016.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the old (depricated) API version. Please check your URL and ensure it matches this: http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap...

Comment: Thanks for your quick response, I tried using below link also still error is same. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/static-maps/intro

Comment: I'm assuming you're using a scatter chart? If so, please share what you have in your 'Dynamic Image' expression in the Colors tab.